# copy cell value down until some condition

Tags: excel, vba

In excel 2013 I have a lot of data file with this structure:

```
  ae:|xxxxx|yyyyy|
    1|aaaaa|bbbbb|
    2|ccccc|ddddd|
...
total|?????|!!!!!|
  ae:|zzzzz|wwwww|
   41|asdas|aswww|
   42|hfghf|yuytu|
...
total|?????|!!!!!|
...
```

Need you help that where is "?????" to place the data that is after "ae:" cell.
for the example above must be:

```
  ae:|xxxxx|yyyyy|
    1|aaaaa|bbbbb|
    2|ccccc|ddddd|
...
total|xxxxx|yyyyy|
  ae:|zzzzz|wwwww|
   41|asdas|aswww|
   42|hfghf|yuytu|
...
total|zzzzz|wwwww|
...
```

any help will be apreciated.
thnx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a bare bones VBA subroutine to do this. This is all pretty basic stuff and should be more than enough to get you pointed in the right direction for your workbook. Please give a good attempt to modify this for your needs before asking follow up question.

```
Sub getTotal()
    Dim intLastRow as integer
    Dim intRow as integer
    Dim strAEval1 as string 'variable to hold your first ae value
    Dim strAEval2 as string 'variable to hold your second ae value

    intLastRow = 5000 'change this to your last row in your spreadsheet

    'Assuming this data is in Sheet1, Columns A, B, and C and starting at Row 1
    ' loop through each row 
    for intRow = 1 to intLastRow

        'if you find 'ae' then copy the values
        If Sheet1.Range("A" & intRow).value = "ae:" Then
            strAEval1 = Sheet1.Range("B" & intRow).value
            straeval2 = Sheet1.Range("C" & intRow).value

        'if you find 'total' then paste the values we copied
        Elseif Sheet1.Range("A" & intRow).value = "total" Then
            Sheet1.Range("B" & intRow).value = strAEval1
            Sheet1.Range("C" & intRow).value = strAEval2
        End if
    Next intRow
End Sub
```